# Oracle query to count and group specific field

Tags: oracle

I have the following example table:

```
FIELD1     FIELD2      FIELD3
12345      888555      009999
12345      888555      327777
12345      888555      327777
54321      999666      334444
54321      999666      324444
55501      999333      005555
55501      999333      350000
55501      999333      890000
55501      999333      320000
```

Now, assuming FIELD1 and FIELD2 have always the same value, e.g. if FIELD1 = 12345 then FIELD2 will be always 888555, what I have to do is make a query where I count FIELD1 and FIELD2 occurencies when the first 2 digits of FIELD3 = 32 and when the first 2 digits of FIELD3 IS NOT 32.

In above case I should have as output:

```
FIELD1  FIELD2    FIELD3    COUNT
12345   888555    32            2
54321   999666    NOT32         1
54321   999666    32            1
55501   999333    32            1
55501   999333    NOT32         3
```

Could someone help me to achieve that?

**EDIT:** Thank you to @Akina who suggest me the following solution (it seems to work):

```
select FIELD1, 
       FIELD2, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(FIELD3, 1, 2) = '32' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FIELD3_EQU_32, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(FIELD3, 1, 2) = '32' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as FIELD3_NEQ_32
from TABLE
group by FIELD1, 
         FIELD2;
```

What I need now is output only a count who exceed a specif threshold,
something like:

```
       HAVING ((FIELD3_EQU_32 > '10' and SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,3)='888')  
       or (FIELD3_NEQ_32 > '5' and SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,3)='999')
etc...
```

Thank you very much.
Lucas

Answer (score 2):

```
select FIELD1, 
       FIELD2, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(FIELD3, 1, 2) = '32' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FIELD3_EQU_32, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(FIELD3, 1, 2) = '32' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as FIELD3_NEQ_32
from TABLE
group by FIELD1, 
         FIELD2;
```

Comment: Thank you Akina, it seems working fine, please help me now to understand how to archive the following (ALSO REPORTED IN THE FIRST POST). What I need now is output only a count who exceed a specif threshold, something like:

       HAVING ((FIELD3_EQU_32 > '10' and SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,3)='888')  
       or (FIELD3_NEQ_32 > '5' and SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,3)='999')

Comment: @LucasRey The condition by `SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,3)` must be placed into WHERE.

Comment: thank you, but what I need is output only the counter who exceed a specific threshold AND with SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,3).   Example:  OUTPUT ONLY     FIELD3_EQU_32 > '10' and SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,3)='888'

Comment: If you need to test the condition by FIELD3_EQU_32 for a list of SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,3) values then you must add `SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,3)` into both output list and GROUP BY expression instead of `FIELD2`.

Comment: Ok, but I need complete field2 on output for later analisys.

I tried to add:

where (FIELD3_EQU_32 > '50' and SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,3)='888')

but I got:
"FIELD3_EQU_32": invalid identifier

Comment: *but I got: "FIELD3_EQU_32": invalid identifier* Output column alias cannot be used in WHERE - in HAVING only. And backward with source table column. *I need complete field2 on output for later analisys* You cannot obtain the data of 2 different grouping level in one query. Either complete FIELD2 value or a substring of it. And you cannot obtain the whole value after grouping by its substring.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232216/discussion-between-lucas-rey-and-akina).